# Yii2 BootstrapAsset is not loading bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

`yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset` is not loading `bootstrap.js`, and such elements as "modal" and others are not working.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [    
        /* theme */
        'css/site.css',

        /* jasny bootstrap */
        'public/jasny/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css',

        /* font awesome */
        'public/font-awesome-430/css/font-awesome.min.css',

        /* font roboto */
        'public/fonts/roboto/roboto.css',

        /* Data Tables */
        'public/datatables/extensions/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css',  
    ];

    public $js = [    
        /* jasny bootstrap  */
        'public/jasny/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js',

        /* Data Tables  */
        'public/datatables/datajs.js',
        'public/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
        'public/datatables/extensions/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js',               
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];    
}
```

[Here](http://prntscr.com/76z2fa) is screen of libraries, `bootstrap.js` is missing there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try it:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'css/mystyle.css',
];
public $js = [

];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];
}
```

Answer (score 31):

If you look at the content of `BootstrapAsset` bundle, you will see that there is no `bootstrap.js`:

```
class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];
}
```

For `bootstrap.js` another asset bundle exists and it's called `BootstrapPluginAsset`:

```
class BootstrapPluginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $js = [
        'js/bootstrap.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

The full class name with namespace is: `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset`.

It's included automatically when you use js dependent bootstrap widgets such as `yii\bootstrap\Modal`, etc.

Comment: in $depends i need to call  ¿BootstrapPluginAsset? for the 'js/bootstrap.js'?

Comment: Yes, you can include it in `depends` section of your asset bundle.

Comment: What could I do if I want to know the hierarchical dependency of an `AssetBundle`? In other words, in this case, I want to know where `BootstrapPluginAsset` is regarded as a dependency?   @arogachev

Answer (score 10):

when you add dependency

```
 public $depends = [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
```

its only add bootstrap css

while you add

```
 public $depends = [
     'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
```

its add bootstrap css as well as js

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the main configuration file (`config/web.php`):

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'js' => ['js/bootstrap.js'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in AppAsset.php

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
  'css/mystyle.css',
];
public $js = [

];
public $depends = [
'yii\web\YiiAsset',
'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];
}
```

and also change in you config/main.php

```
'components' => [
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'js' => ['js/bootstrap.min.js'],
        ],
    ],
],
],
```

I have tried these steps that will solve my problem thats to all for your comment